# Getting gem exception while deployin code on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

Hi i am getting a gem exception error:

```
Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/Ascii85-1.0.1.gem] in /home/profweb/rails-apps/profitnext/releases/20120628123949
 ** [out :: profitnext.com] An error occured while installing Ascii85 (1.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
 ** [out :: profitnext.com] Make sure that `gem install Ascii85 -v '1.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
    command finished in 607967ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

Although i have installed that gem in gem file and it shows in gem list on local host. Can somebody tell me why i am getting this error in "cap deploy" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have all dependencies installed on the remote host? Similar errors are produced if you're installing a gem and don't have required packages installed on your system

Comment: How do i know this, i have already installed all the required gems.

Comment: So you are able to install this gem on remote host (not your local one) and install goes fine?

Comment: No sir i have this gem installed on local host but unable to install on remote host.Thank for reply. I am suffering with a slow network connection from last few days may be because of this i am unable to deploy my code.

Comment: You should try to login to remote host and try to install this gem, it will probably fail because your remote system lacks some libraries that are required for it (i'm just guessing). If so you'll need to find out which libs they are and install them

Answer (score 0):

i got where the real problem is. I have added a line in my "deploy.rb" file and added the required gem in my gemfile and run the bundle install. Now i can easily deploy my code. Thanks for reply friends.